# Synonym request for Flash builder tags

Tags: discussion, support, tags, tag-synonyms, retag-request

Can someone merge the [flash-builder](/questions/tagged/flash-builder) tag with the [flashbuilder](/questions/tagged/flashbuilder) tag? They're synonyms with one another, and there's no need to have both of them.

And maybe we also need to do something with [flashbuilder4](/questions/tagged/flashbuilder4) tag, not sure about this one. Any ideas?

Right now (at the time when I created this post) we have the following questions that use these tags:

- [flashbuilder](/questions/tagged/flashbuilder) - 135
- [flash-builder](/questions/tagged/flash-builder) - 618
- [flashbuilder4](/questions/tagged/flashbuilder4)  - 55

Comment: The `[flash-builder4]` tag *might* be useful if there are a sufficient number of changes made to version 4 that people might be asking specific questions about. Otherwise, version tags are strongly discouraged. I don't know enough about Flash Builder to have an opinion in this particular case.

Comment: @Cody yes you are right, I wasn't sure about that one, but now I'm thinking that maybe it makes sense to change it to flash-builder-4 to be consistent with SE tag name pattern.